# Is $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

If I type $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot  \cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$
in maple, it gives as output 0. 
Is this correct and if so, why?

I've tried the following myself:

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{\cos k}{k}\ldots$ ?

Am I on the right track or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I find hard to believe Maple didn't get this right. I'd suggest you share the input you typed in Maple, may be we can help you spot an error related to how you used it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you tried yourself is correct. Also, note that as $n \to \infty$, then $\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \to \cos(0) = 1$. Thus, you should be getting

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = \infty \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

I'm not sure why Maple is giving you a limit of $0$. However, if you use a limit of $n \to 0$ instead, then since $-1 \le \cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \le 1$, you would then get $0$. Perhaps you entered the limit value into Maple incorrectly?